# Sass selector combine attribute

Tags: html, css, sass

I want to use `font-family: 'Noto Sans TC'` in specific language, so I wrote the following code in `.scss`.

```
body{
  &[lang="en"]{ font-family: 'Noto Sans TC', sans-serif; }
  &[lang="zh-TW"]{ font-family: 'Noto Sans TC', sans-serif; }
  &[lang="zh-CN"]{ font-family: 'Noto Sans SC', sans-serif; }
}
```

Then in html

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').attr('lang', translationManager.getCurrentLanguage());
});
```

It works fine, but I was wondering is there a better way to write the `.scss` code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SASS is a powerful CSS tool to make use of in programming. It provides a lot of programming logics support like `if/else, each, for loop, etc.`, so in your situation it's better to make use of `@each` functions in SASS-

```
$langs: 'en','zh-TW','zh-CN'; // Define the array for your languages

@each $lang in $langs{
  body{
     &[lang="#{$lang}"]{
        font-family: 'Noto Sans TC', sans-serif;
     }
  }
}
```

this will result in something like this-

```
body[lang="en"] {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans TC', sans-serif;
}

body[lang="zh-TW"] {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans TC', sans-serif;
}

body[lang="zh-CN"] {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans TC', sans-serif;
}
```

You can check this here - http://www.sassmeister.com/,

Also it depends what kind of compiler tool you're using, for ex. if you're using gulp and it's `gulp-sass` package it'll minimize the code and write it in a comma-seperated way.

For more experiments and advance features refer the below links-

http://thesassway.com/intermediate/if-for-each-while

https://www.sitepoint.com/sass-maps-vs-nested-lists/

https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks for the references as well, very useful.